# Trying to convert a custom vanilla javascript dropdown menu for use in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu

I'm pretty new with React (and JS in general for that matter), but I'm trying to get a dropdown menu (that will eventually work like a query selector for a search bar) to work with some custom styling.

I found a perfect solution at w3schools with inline javascript. The problem is I can't seem to get it to work in a react application. Maybe it's as simple as some syntax changes between vanilla JS and React, but so far it doesn't work. Any advice would be appreciated.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_custom_select

Answer (score 1):

Of course, we can use any available select item library out there. One of my favourites is [headles.ui](https://headlessui.com/react/listbox).
But if we want to master react, it is better to learn to make it from scratch.

So, Let's do it with **React Way** to make it works.

First of all, we need to keep in mind that React deals with **state**. So, we will use **state** to convert your example into React app.

Here, we will not use plain `<select>` & `<option>` tag since this is a **Custom Select**. The data we put inside an **selectItems** array:

```js
const selectItems = [
    "Audi",
    "BMW",
    "Citroen",
    "Ford",
    "Honda",
    "Jaguar",
    "Land Rover",
    "Mercedes",
    "Mini",
    "Nissan",
    "Toyota",
    "Volvo",
];
```

Next, we define two state in our component which are **active** state and **selected** state.

```js
// this state will be used in conditional rendering of our list items
// the value is boolean and the default is false (not active)
const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

// this state will keep our selected item
const [selected, setSelected] = useState("Select car:");
```

To open and close the **List Items**, we need to define a **toggle** method, that will toggle the active state by negating the previous state:

```js
const toggle = () => setActive((prevState) => !prevState);
```

And whenever the user click a **List Item**, the element will set the **selected** state with the element **item** value, and hide the List Items by calling the toggle method:

```js
const handleItemClick = (item) => {
    setSelected(item);
    toggle();
};
```

In order to render the selected item and the list items, we need to create two sections:

```
return (
    <div>
        ...
        {/* at onClick listener we pass toggle method */}
        <div className="select-selected" onClick={toggle}>
            // Selected Item section
        </div>
        <div className="select-items">
            // Select Items section
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

At Selected Item, we define **conditional class name** and add **selected** state. The className will have value `select-selected select-arrow-active` if state active value is true and will be `select-selected` only if otherwise.

```
return (
    ...
    <div className={`select-selected ${active ? 'select-arrow-active' : ''}`} onClick={toggle}>
        {selected}
    </div>
)
```

And lastly, we render the List items by using javascript map method:

```
return (
    ...
    <div className="select-items">
        {/* we render list items only when active state is true */}
        {active && selectItems.map((item,i) => {
            return (
                <div
                    key={i}
                    onClick={() => handleItemClick(item)}
                    {/* when the selected item equal to the item then use "same-as-selected" className */}
                    className={`${item === selected ? "same-as-selected": ""}`}
                >
                    {item}
                </div>
            )
        })}
    </div>
    ...
)
```

And finally, this is the complete code. Minimal example but at least have followed the given vanilla javascript example.
You can see our select item component in action by clicking the blue **Run code snippet** button below.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const selectItems = [
    "Audi",
    "BMW",
    "Citroen",
    "Ford",
    "Honda",
    "Jaguar",
    "Land Rover",
    "Mercedes",
    "Mini",
    "Nissan",
    "Toyota",
    "Volvo",
];

function App() {
    const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState("Select car:");

    const toggle = () => setActive((prevState) => !prevState);

    const handleItemClick = (item) => {
        setSelected(item);
        toggle();
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Custom Select</h2>
            <div className="custom-select">
                <div className={`select-selected ${active ? 'select-arrow-active' : ''}`} onClick={toggle}>
                   {selected}
                </div>
                <div className="select-items">
                    {active && selectItems.map((item,i) => {
                        return (
                            <div
                                key={i}
                                onClick={() => handleItemClick(item)}
                                className={`${item === selected ? "same-as-selected": ""}`}
                            >
                                {item}
                            </div>
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```css
.custom-select {
    position: relative;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 200px;
}

.select-selected {
    background-color: DodgerBlue;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.select-selected:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 14px;
    right: 10px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 6px solid transparent;
    border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}

.select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
    border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
    top: 7px;
}

.select-items div,.select-selected {
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
}

.select-items {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: DodgerBlue;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 99;
}

.select-items div:hover, .same-as-selected {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div class='react'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Blake.

So React components are typically built in a much different way to how this example would be built. React requires use of State to update the interface and we don't use  tags.

I would recommend, instead of spending much time converting this example, finding an existing React drop-down package that works the same way.

[This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dropdown) is a great existing package for creating React drop-downs and I have used it myself in the past. Follow the guide on there and you'll have it implemented in no time.

Hope this helped explain it and welcome to the React community!